# getting error while updating Composer

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

I have a project in Laravel-5.1 and I have changed my platform from win10 to Ubuntu.

Showing error:

> Loading composer repositories with package information
>
> Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
>
> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

```
  Problem 1
- laravel/framework v5.2.9 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework v5.2.8 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework v5.2.7 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework v5.2.6 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework v5.2.5 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework v5.2.4 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework v5.2.31 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework v5.2.30 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework v5.2.3 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework v5.2.29 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework v5.2.28 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework v5.2.27 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework v5.2.26 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework v5.2.25 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework v5.2.24 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework v5.2.23 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework v5.2.22 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework v5.2.21 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework v5.2.20 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework v5.2.2 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework v5.2.19 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework v5.2.18 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework v5.2.17 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework v5.2.16 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework v5.2.15 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework v5.2.14 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework v5.2.13 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework v5.2.12 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework v5.2.11 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework v5.2.10 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework v5.2.1 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework v5.2.0 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- laravel/framework v5.2.30 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
- Installation request for laravel/framework 5.2.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.2.0, v5.2.1, v5.2.10, v5.2.11, v5.2.12, v5.2.13, v5.2.14, v5.2.15, v5.2.16, v5.2.17, v5.2.18, v5.2.19, v5.2.2, v5.2.20, v5.2.21, v5.2.22, v5.2.23, v5.2.24, v5.2.25, v5.2.26, v5.2.27, v5.2.28, v5.2.29, v5.2.3, v5.2.30, v5.2.31, v5.2.4, v5.2.5, v5.2.6, v5.2.7, v5.2.8, v5.2.9].

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in those .ini files:
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

Composer/json.

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"require": {
  "php": ">=5.5.9",
  "laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
  "infyomlabs/laravel-generator": "dev-master",
  "laravelcollective/html": "5.2.*",
  "infyomlabs/core-templates": "dev-master",
  "infyomlabs/swagger-generator": "dev-master",
  "jlapp/swaggervel": "dev-master",
  "doctrine/dbal": "~2.3",
  "infyomlabs/generator-builder": "dev-master",
  "yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle": "~6.0",
  "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "^2.1",
  "infyomlabs/adminlte-templates": "dev-master"
},
"require-dev": {
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
    "symfony/css-selector": "2.8.*|3.0.*",
    "symfony/dom-crawler": "2.8.*|3.0.*"
},
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "classmap": [
        "tests/TestCase.php"
    ]
},
"scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "php artisan key:generate"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist"
}
```

}

Comment: Hi @kkpatel, please put a minimal working example, what you have done to fix your issue.

Comment: @Andy K  need to install mbstring , yum and xml for php7.0 and beet change in php.ini file.

Comment: that's James giving you the answer. Not what you have done to find the issue

Answer (score 120, accepted):

Your error message is pretty explicit about what is going wrong:

> laravel/framework v5.2.9 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.

Do you have `mbstring` installed on your server and is it enabled?

You can install `mbstring` as part of the libapache2-mod-php5 package:

`sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5`

Or standalone with:

`sudo apt-get install php-mbstring`

Installing it will also enable it, however you can also enable it by editing your `php.ini` file and remove the `;` that is commenting it out if it is already installed.

If this is on your local machine, then follow the appropriate steps to install this on your environment.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong: *and remove the `;` commenting it out* you meant *uncommenting it out*, as the semi colon represents the comment, right ?

Comment: @SaiyanPrince i have edited my answer - but I meant to say that having the semi colon there was currently commenting it out

Comment: @James Thank you for providing the clarification but your edit has not made any change. I still find it unclear from my side.. It should be uncommenting and not commenting..

Comment: @SaiyanPrince "the `;` that is commenting it out" is the correct English in this case.

Comment: why does composer not downoald the libary ext-mbstring automatically? I thought its a package manager?

Comment: @Adam Composer is a *package* manager and not a *module* manager. Ext-mbstring is a php module that you need to install and enable on your server, as opposed to a php package which is installed in your project.

Answer (score 45):

for php7 you can do that:

```
sudo apt-get install php-gd php-xml php7.0-mbstring
```

Comment: for php 7.2 I used sudo apt-get install php-gd php-xml php7.2-mbstring

Comment: Finally! Thank you very much, kind sir.

Answer (score 14):

In php7.2 Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and ubuntu 19.04

```
sudo apt-get install php-gd php-xml php7.2-mbstring
```

Works like a Charm

Answer (score 8):

**The quick solution for this error**

*run this command*

`composer install --ignore-platform-reqs`

**This command not consider operating system or platform**

Comment: It worked for me. Composer was checking platform requirements but actually the reqs are already satisfied. After running this command, everything worked as expected

Answer (score 7):

If you're using php 7.3 for laravel 5.7. this work for me

```
sudo apt-get install php-gd php-xml php7.3-mbstring
```

Comment: It was only way that it works for me, i am using: PHP Version 7.2.24-1 + ubuntu16.04.1 + deb.sury.org + Laravel 5.8.35

Answer (score 3):

After installing packages from given answers, i still get some errors then i install following package and it works fine:

- php-xml

for specific version:

- php7.0-xml

command for **php 7.0**

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-xml
```

in some cases you also needs a package *php7.0-common* . install it same as above command.

Comment: it seems php version is important here... I tried couple of time with php-xml instead of php7.*-xml.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of good answers already for Ubuntu. I'm on Linux and had the same problem but none of the commands above worked for me.

With Linux and php70 I used the following command which worked great:

`sudo yum install php70-mbstring -y`

Answer (score 1):

This works for me with php 7.2

`sudo apt-get install php7.2-xml`

Answer (score 1):

Problem :

```
Problem 1
    - laravel/framework v5.8.38 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.8.38 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.8.38 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for laravel/framework (locked at v5.8.38, required as 5.8.*) -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.8.38].

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - C:\xampp\php\php.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

Solution :


if you using xampp just remove ' ; ' from

```
;extension=mbstring
```

in php.ini , save it, done!

Answer (score 0):

In php7.4

> sudo apt-get install php-gd php-xml php7.4-mbstring