# composer install doesn't work in phpstorm

Tags: php, composer-php

I clone a laravel repository from github. I want install it on phpstorm but when I run this command `composer install` in terminal environment, this error appeared:

```
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.7.9 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP    
      ...
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.2.0 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for phpunit/phpunit ^5.2 -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[5..., 5.7.7, 5.7.8, 5.7.9].

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini
      ...
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

and this is my composer.json file:

```
{
    "name": "cydrobolt/polr",
    "description": "The Polr URL Shortener.",
    "keywords": ["url-shortener", "url", "cms"],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "laravel/lumen-framework": "5.1.*",
        "vlucas/phpdotenv": "~1.0",
        "illuminate/mail": "~5.1",
        "google/recaptcha": "~1.1"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^5.2",
        "symfony/css-selector": "^3.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "database/"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    }
}
```

I try [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36979121/10616617) but it doesn't work. **What is the problem?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing an extension in your php.ini setting. Install the extension for ext-dom, then reload/restart your server and run "composer install" again.

If your using Linux with apt-get then you can install ext-dom with this command:

```
sudo apt-get install php-xml
```