# "Could not find driver" message when executing query

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, composer-php

I have a Laravel project. It was fine until I updated my Ubuntu 19.04 to 19.10. While testing my APIs on Postman I get this error:

```
"message": "could not find driver (SQL: select * from `users` where `username` = genesis limit 1)",
"exception": "Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException",
"file": "/home/arkhalis/Repos/laravel/safetrade/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php",
"line": 664
```

and after that I tried to run `Composer` on terminal and got this output

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\mb_detect_encoding() in /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Helper/Helper.php:50
Stack trace:
#0 /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Descriptor/TextDescriptor.php(329): Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\Helper::strlen('h')
#1 /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Descriptor/TextDescriptor.php(97): Symfony\Component\Console\Descriptor\TextDescriptor->calculateTotalWidthForOptions(Array)
#2 /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Descriptor/TextDescriptor.php(197): Symfony\Component\Console\Descriptor\TextDescriptor->describeInputDefinition(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputDefinition), Array)
#3 /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Descriptor/Descriptor.php(55): Symfony\Component\Console\Descriptor\TextDescriptor->describeApplication(Object(Composer\Console\Application), Array)
#4 /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Helper/DescriptorHelper.php(67): Symfony\Component\Console\Descriptor\Descriptor->describ in /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Helper/Helper.php on line 50

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\mb_detect_encoding() in /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Helper/Helper.php:50
Stack trace:
#0 /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Descriptor/TextDescriptor.php(329): Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\Helper::strlen('h')
#1 /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Descriptor/TextDescriptor.php(97): Symfony\Component\Console\Descriptor\TextDescriptor->calculateTotalWidthForOptions(Array)
#2 /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Descriptor/TextDescriptor.php(197): Symfony\Component\Console\Descriptor\TextDescriptor->describeInputDefinition(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputDefinition), Array)
#3 /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Descriptor/Descriptor.php(55): Symfony\Component\Console\Descriptor\TextDescriptor->describeApplication(Object(Composer\Console\Application), Array)
#4 /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Helper/DescriptorHelper.php(67): Symfony\Component\Console\Descriptor\Descriptor->describ in /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Helper/Helper.php on line 50
```

Also I have tried to run `composer update` and got the same result as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36979019/getting-error-while-updating-composer) and run `sudo apt-get install php-mbstring` but the same result as I run `composer` command on terminal.

Comment: do you have `php-mysql` plugin installed? it says "could not find driver"

Comment: I'm not sure, how can I check if it is installed? But my mysql version is `8.0.17`

Comment: run `apt install lamp-server^` mind the caret at the end.

Comment: Man this should be an answer! Fixed my problem and I can run `composer` without errors, great :)

Comment: And ohh. well yeah running `composer` is fine but `composer update` is the same

Comment: why are you running `composer update`?

Comment: I suggest OP to install package individually, not via lamp-server ;))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to install all the required extension by Laravel. Please take a look [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/installation#server-requirements).

You can try to run this command if you're using PHP 7.1:

```sh
sudo apt install php7.1 php7.1-fpm php7.1-curl php7.1-mysql php7.1-common php7.1-mbstring php7.1-mcrypt php7.1-xml
```

Or you can run this command if you're using PHP7.2 (no mcrypt, since it's has been removed)

```sh
sudo apt install php7.2 php7.2-fpm php7.2-curl php7.2-mysql php7.2-common php7.2-mbstring php7.2-xml
```

If you're experiencing an error, maybe you don't have any PHP repo added. Try to add this complete PHP repo by **Ondřej Surý**.

```sh
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt update
```

**Update**

Since you're using Ubuntu 19.10 (Eoan), I've heard that by default It comes with PHP 7.3. So, maybe you could try:

```sh
sudo apt install php php-fpm php-curl php-mysql php-common php-mbstring php-xml
```

Right now the `ondrej/php` still not release any PHP packages for 19.10 (because Ubuntu 19.10 is released recently). It takes time for the author to released the packages.

Comment: I have tried that one on php7.2, this is the result https://pastebin.com/8LTDK72w and the 2nd command doesn't fix the issue either.

Comment: You forget to `sudo apt update` after adding repo. That's basic ubuntu command. Ok, i'll edit my answer.

Comment: yes of course I have `sudo apt update` earlier, here's the result https://pastebin.com/phm49kQA if u must see

Comment: Ok, so you're using Ubuntu 19.10? Then, I think the package still not released. I will update my answer to reflect your distro, hope it works, since I'm not using the 19.10 yet.

Comment: Yes, maybe that's the case. I should rollback my distro then

Comment: Yes, now I can run `composer update` without problem, but here's a result https://pastebin.com/bwGUT1Ws it says it returned an error code

Comment: However now I can throw a request successfully, so this fixed my problem, thank you :D

Comment: @Mr.Benbenbenbenben I don't know where's the mysql-server comes from, since I'm not mention to install that package. Glad if your issue is solved.